# SCP QGIS sentinel 2 authorization error

Tags: qgis, digital-image-processing

I am using Qgis 2.18.16, when i tried to download sentinel 2 via SCP interface, I am getting following error:

```
Authentication Required
```

[image]

Comment: Have you got an account? https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/1SelfRegistration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download Sentinel data using the SCP-Plugin you must register first [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/1SelfRegistration). Once registration is complete, it is also likely to take a couple days before you are able to use an API, like the one incorporated in the SCP-Plugin.

More information is available in this official [tutorial](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_2.html) by SCP, where he explains:
"WARNING : The guest/guest account is not available anymore. Free registration is required. See https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News00097."

Comment: I have created an account today, its not working either.

Comment: As I mentioned, after registering it can  take a couple days until you can use the API via the SCP-plugin. It should work eventually.

Answer (score 1):

it is working now. it takes 24 hours after registration to work and guest login credentials are removed. so if anyone wants to download satellite data via SCP plugin in Qgis, one has to register using following link
"https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News00097."